# How to capture `currentSrc` of a srcset instead of `attr(src)` for an inline background image in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, plugins, srcset

I'm using the jQuery plugin [MaxImage.js](http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/) to create a full-screen background slideshow on a site under development.

The plugin code reads the DOM, grabs the target images and clones them to be background images on new divs with inline-styles. The code involved is:

```js
$self.children().each(function(i) {
  var $img = $(this).is('img') ? $(this).clone() : $(this).find('img').first().clone();
  // reset obj
  obj = {};
  // set attributes to obj
  obj.url = $img.attr('src');
  obj.title = $img.attr('title') != undefined ? $img.attr('title') : '';
  obj.alt = $img.attr('alt') != undefined ? $img.attr('alt') : '';
  obj.theclass = $img.attr('class') != undefined ? $img.attr('class') : '';
  obj.styles = $img.attr('style') != undefined ? $img.attr('style') : '';
  obj.orig = $img.clone();
  obj.datahref = $img.attr('data-href') != undefined ? $img.attr('data-href') : '';
  obj.content = "";
  // Setup content for within container
  if ($(this).find('img').length > 0) {
    if ($.BrowserTests.cssBackgroundSize) {
      $(this).find('img').first().remove();
    }
    obj.content = $(this).html();
  }
  // Stop loading image so we can load them sequentiallyelse{
  $img[0].src = "";
  // Remove original object (only on nonIE. IE hangs if you remove an image during load)
  if ($.BrowserTests.cssBackgroundSize) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
  // attach obj to arr
  arr.push(obj);
});
```

The line I need to change is **line 6**, where the new inline background image URL is set by simply grabbing the current `src`:

```
obj.url = $img.attr('src');
```

I'd like to swap the `attr(src)` call to grab the image's `currentSrc` property, since this would account properly for the size of the viewport. The `srcset` is working properly and loading the appropriately-sized image if I disable the script, but I cannot come up with any variation of code to grab the `currentSrc` instead of `attr(src)`, I just get an `undefined` result.

I've tried…

```
$img.prop('currentSrc');
$img.get(0).currentSrc;
```

…and other variants.

Any ideas? I'm stumped. That this is within a jQuery plugin might complicate matters, but I'm only going by some of the similar solutions offered here on Stack Overflow that do not work in this case.

Comment: a backgroundimage is not the same as an src. You probably want to do something like $(obj).css("backgroundImage", "url(" + imagepath  + ")")

Comment: Thanks for the assist, but this isn't the problem. The code provided here shows the various attributes being read from the existing DOM image nodes and being repurposed to become inline elements for a dynamically created div. Even if I modified the code elsewhere, *this* snippet of code at line 6 is setting what will be used as the background-image to attr(src), which brings me full circle to my original query. If there is *anywhere* to fix this issue, it's at line 6.

Comment: `obj.url = $img.prop('currentSrc')` seems to work for me (in Chrome, at least): http://jsfiddle.net/erESt/568/

Comment: Huh! It's the version of jQuery. Your default in the Fiddle is v1.7. If I step to ANYTHING more current it fails. Anyway to target jQuery 1.7 to this one particular script and use a more modern version on the rest of the site?

Comment: I guess this isn't too shocking since it's a 4 year old script without much attention. I'm using it instead of UIKit's built-in slideshow (which works beautifully everywhere EXCEPT iOS) because iOS doesn't handle background-size:cover properly on dynamically-sized elements. That's a whole other issue.

Comment: nm. noConflict(true). got it. duh.

Comment: Tried isolating the jQuery 1.7 namespace for just the Maximage.js code, which is very brief. Not working. I'd like to keep the `$` call for jQuery v3.x and use a different var (jq1) for the jQuery v1.7 code. Clearly I'm screwing something up as it's not working. Fresh eyes in the AM, unless anyone else has further input.